# How do I disable certain keys using a key in AutoHotkey?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want the "End" key to block/lock certain keys like a,s,d,i,j,k,l. And when I click "End" again to unblock the same keys (a,s,d,i,j,k,l). How can I do this in Autohotkey? Can someone please tell me the commands and functions?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I think @user 99572 is fine should be marked answer; it was very specific and thorough.

Answer (score 14):

AutoHotkey has 2 functions that might help you:

1. "Suspend", which will stop all hotkeys in a script from working.
2. "return", which can be used to disable single keys or hotkeys (and mouse buttons).

Now you can turn these 2 functions to your advantage.

Just place this line of code somewhere in your script:

```
end::Suspend
```

This will suspend the script when you press <kbd>End</kbd>. Once the script is suspended, the keys will function normally. Once you activate the script with <kbd>End</kbd>, the keys will be disabled.

You can disable keys by running a script like this:

```
a::return
b::return
...
```

Works like a charm.

Just for simplicity's sake, the whole script will look like this:

```
end::Suspend
a::return
b::return
```

Just add any keys you want to disable below the last return. If you want to disable other keys than letters or numbers, just consult the comprehensive [Key List](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm). Place the name of the key before the 2 colons: e.g. NumPad0::return

Save the script in a file with extension .ahk, like "disablekeys.ahk". Double click on it or create a shortcut to it in the startup folder if you want it to start automatically. Done.

Comment: You don't have to use `return`, `[key]::` is enough.

Comment: @user598527 You're right.

Comment: Any idea how I can make this work in a particular application? https://superuser.com/questions/1427953/disable-ctrlt-shortcut-in-onenote-using-ahk/1427958#1427958

Comment: @JanacMeena I see you got the answer. TitleMatch is a bit cumbersome to get right.

Answer (score 0):

**Activate:**

1. In Windows, you can pin it to taskbar or startmenu

2. right click pinned icon and click properties 

3. give that a shortcut key which can be used to call/activate

**Deactivate:**

You can suspend ahk script via

```
#Pause::Suspend
```

Not a good solution but works