# Disable "ctrl+t" shortcut in OneNote using AHK

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm a beginner at AHK.

How can I disable the `ctrl+t` shortcut in OneNote using AutoHotKey?

My attempt so far at a script:

```
; use regular expressions for matching titles
SetTitleMatchMode,RegEx

#IfWinActive, ^ONENOTE.*
+insert::msgbox ctrl+t
#IfWinActive
```

I just put `insert::msgbox` but I would prefer if nothing at all happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/554431/302907), try simply using `^t::` in place of `+insert::msgbox ctrl+t`. Also note that the proper regular expression appears to (roughly) be `(.*)OneNote(.*)`, as `OneNote` always seems to be included in the Window Title (`ONENOTE.EXE` is the executable name).

> How can I disable the `Ctrl + T` shortcut in OneNote using AutoHotKey?

Generally speaking, the following script should block the `Ctrl + T` shortcut in OneNote:

```
; use regular expressions for matching titles
SetTitleMatchMode,RegEx

#IfWinActive, (.*)OneNote(.*)
    ^t::
#IfWinActive
```

Note that if you have this script running, nothing should happen when you press `Ctrl + T`. You can verify that the script is working by assigning `^t::` a message box:

```
; use regular expressions for matching titles
SetTitleMatchMode,RegEx

#IfWinActive, (.*)OneNote(.*)
    ^t::msgbox Sorry, Ctrl + T has been disabled!
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Looks like that's a step in the right direction, but still I'm unable to even trigger the message box while in OneNote - so using `^t::` did not work.

Any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. In short, my guess would be that you are looking for the wrong string in your regular expression.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. =)